# How to perform text classification inference using the huggingface transformer's library

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

To Whom It May Concern,

After training a `binary classification model` via `examples/run_glue.py`, I have a the following files.

```
merges.txt
tokenizer_config.json
config.json
pytorch_model.bin
training_args.bin
special_tokens_map.json
vocab.json
```

I can evaluate this model via the same script and the `--do_eval` arg; however, I would like to use this model to do `inference` not `evaluation`, as I don't have the labels for the unseen data I will be feeding into it. What is the best way to accomplish this using the main library? I currently use [fast-bert](https://github.com/kaushaltrivedi/fast-bert). However, I'm transitioning this into a production pipeline and consequently can't stray from the main library anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Chris